# scipy and excel result are different in T distribution

Tags: python, excel, statistics

scipy and excel result are different in T distribution

The values from scipy and excel for 95% double tail t values are different.
The conditions are degrees of freedom is 59,

in scipy

```
from scipy import stats
print (stats.t.ppf(1-0.025, 59)) 
2.00099537704821
```

in excel

```
TINV(0.025, 59)
2.3000469
```

Those are supposed to be same but different. Which is right?

Comment: The docs of `TINV` say it has been replaced with more accurate functions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tinv-function-a7c85b9d-90f5-41fe-9ca5-1cd2f3e1ed7c although you'll get the same number...

Comment: The python result is correct, for `TINV` in excel, it is already a two tail test so you shouldn't divide the probability by two i.e. it should be `TINV(0.05, 59)` to be equivalent to your python code

Comment: @Dan Thanks for quick response, You're totally right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a two tail requirement for python
from scipy import stats
print (stats.t.ppf(1-0.025/2, 59))
answer: python3 tinv.py
2.3000468960888583
This compares with your excel result: =TINV(0.025, 59)
2.3000469
Excel defaults to a two tale test where as python defaults to a one tale test.  That is why you divide the probability by 2.